# How to use scripts to excecute django commands

Tags: python, django, linux, terminal

Hi recently created my website in django. And I have used a web hosting provider who has django, python and my sql installed. But they do not have the ssh option or command prompt in their file manager. How can I use a script to excecute all the commands after uploading my site to the server .

I want file to be created like this updatedb.sh or updatedb.py .

Can anyone tell me how to use the scripts alone to host my django site live.

Comment: What is the web hosting provider? If they have Django, they almost certainly have some way to set it up. (Also, there are some great options such as [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) that can host a Django site and run the appropriate queries to set up the database.)

Comment: You really need to call your hosting service and figure out what they suggest you do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have your Django views execute lines like:

```
import os
os.system("python manage.py syncdb")
```

In theory you could get the site working like that. However, *this is a very poor strategy for deployment.* Aside from the hassle of having os.system lines every time you want to do anything, what will you do if your entire site breaks? You'd be using convoluted hacks just to do the most basic maintenance.

If your web hosting provider truly doesn't support any kind of command line or even give you other options for setting up Django, it's time to find a new web hosting provider. I might recommend [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), which supports Django and lets you deploy using [git](http://git-scm.com/). (It is also free up to a certain amount of use).

Comment: Icky but workable. It's better to use Django's own https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code `call_command` for this.